# Does the ratio of rice:water change if rinsed first?

Tags: rice

In Tim Anderson's Japaneasy he instructs to cook 300g of rice in 390g of water (1:1.3).

He also says to rinse the rice first. When I rinsed the rice and weighted it again after letting water drain, it now weighs 348g.

Should the amount of water I add to the pot to cook it be 390g? Or 342 (subtracting the amount of water absorbed by/clinging to the rice already).

Comment: How is the rice being cooked?  Absorption method on the stove, rice cooker, or something else?

Comment: If that's absorption on the stove then that brings it closer to the ratio I would use without rinsing, ie 1:1.5

Comment: @FuzzyChef absorption on the stove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I went to the bookstore and looked up the basic rice recipe in *Japaneasy*.

The extra water from rinsing the rice is expected.  That's a recipe for cooking on the stovetop by the absorption method, which is normally a 1:1.5 ratio.  And (390 + 48) / 300 is 1.46, just about the same amount.

You'll notice he does not use this formular for rice cookers, which use less water.

Comment: Great answer - so the additional water from rinsing is factored into the recipe already